# Sun control film selection or my bedroom to reduce AC heat load

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a West facing room with large glass windows (approx. 30 sq ft) in a tropical nation. The summer sun heats up the room considerably.

I was thinking of applying sun control film to the windows to reduce the load on my AC. The goal is to get max heat load reduction with minimum light reduction. What do people think of the following specs?
[image]

Also, the website of the company making these films has a bunch of other films on offer. I'm a tad confused if any other film will suit my goal better.

http://www.garwaresuncontrol.com/hhr-grey-70.html

Any tips? What parameters ought to I focus on. There's too many defining each film. Is a Total Solar Energy Rejection of 40% a decent value or can one do better?

Comment: I don't know what they've meant as "Total Solar Energy Rejection". What you need is some of the energy (infrared) reflected but other (visible light) transmitted. 69% transmittance is ok, hardly noticeable. Absorbing IR is also not very good, because the glass will heat up much, it should be reflected back outside.

Comment: Adding an awning to the outside would be a solution unless you don't like the look of awnings.

Comment: What did you do eventually? I'm also leaving in a tropical place where it's hot all year long and was considering films to reduce the heat coming inside, while trying to still keep as much visible light coming in as possible.