# Decreasing heat in glass porch

Tags: heating, sunroom

We have a glass porch (10ft x 20ft) with glass walls and glass roof, connects to the main building through a door. What is the way to decrease the heat inside the room?

Similar to that:

[image]

We can cover the roof with any material, decreasing light is not a problem. Will installing [IR-reflective film](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114969/sun-control-film-selection-or-my-bedroom-to-reduce-ac-heat-load) be enough, or we should put a sail-type light tarp on the ceiling inside / roof outside?

Location: Southern California, US

Comment: Will IR reflective film be enough? Only you can decide that... Will it help? Yes. The best bet is to cover it on the outside, but that creates a maintenance issue and defeats the purpose. Do you have windows in that atrium you can open?

Comment: @FreeMan yes there are some windows, and a "curtain" on wire on the inside of the roof. I plan to install fans to help with airflow.

Comment: Anything _inside_ the glass still allows for thermal gain _through_ the glass. You won't have direct sunlight beating on the floor, but the area between the glass and curtain will get hot and the heat will spill out. Something on the _outside_ will prevent the thermal gain in the first place and be much more efficient. Plant trees to provide shade to the atrium.

Comment: Ventilation would also help if it gets warmer in the porch than outdoors.

Comment: The best solution is a matter of opinion. It involves usage, cost, skill set, etc. You'll need to ask a more specific question. BTW, Monicagate is long over with. I doubt she even wants to come back. Let's move on already.

Comment: Imagine you do to look out the glass roof sometimes, when you are not cooking inside.  Would look into something like retractable awning to go over roof.

Comment: outside treatments would be more effective. The army hangs camo net over sleeping tents to breakup the sun hitting the tent. It can drop the temp inside 20F or more. I doubt you want camo net, but there's more attractive ways to accomplish the same benefits.

Answer (score 3):

You can call one of the tinting places in your area and ask them to put up some ceramic film that will reflect up to 95% of heat. That's what they use on cars now days and it works but kind of pricey. What it does, is blocking UV and IR from heating up your floor and furniture  and unlike the regular tint/film, it will keep those window (glass) cool as well, preventing from radiant heat from seeping through.

Comment: pretty much all window glass blocks UV (which carries little heat), did you mean IR?

Comment: Yes, IR as well as UV. Older homes/windows don't have any coating that will protect from nether UV nor IR.

Comment: I'll suggest that such film might be applied to the _underside_ of the glass roof panels. It'll last much longer than an exterior application.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the following will help.  You can do one of them or all of them:

- Tint and/or reflective coating on the glass.
- A light-colored fabric awning above the roof, attached to it, that rolls up electrically to the apex of the glass roof and unrolls, perhaps along tracks, to completely cover it or maybe even to extend further out over the lawn and shade the side windows too.
- Greenhouse-style vents at the apex of the roof, with fan to assist, pulling hot air up and out through the roof and hopefully cooler air in from entry vents near the floor
- Air conditioning, for example install a mini split here.